# Code Coverage wont Push Tru After IF

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I was trying to create a unit test for my APEX Class.
But i was wondering the Test wont push thru after IF statement but i was using an existing leads (046933) for testing.[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). This means that you can't query the record in your unit test. You must explicitly create records that are to be queried within your unit test, except for some exceptions, like Users, Profiles, and Record Types (see the above link for more details).

Comment: if you say this the cause. I got another test unit that the query push thru.

Comment: @user3751759 It is versioned to certain APIs, and can also be bypassed by SeeAllData=true. See the documentation for details.

Comment: SeeAllData=true.  solved my problem

Comment: @user3751759 `seeAllData=true` is not a good idea for you to use, and you are setting yourself up for failure later. If you use "real" data (i.e. data that was not created in the test class itself), that same data may not be available in other orgs (like your production org). Your test could fail when run for a deployment, or prevent you from attaining the 75% coverage requirement. Test data isolation is a good thing.

Comment: Yep noted on this. Im still new on Salesforce. Will fix it later , this is only a temporary fix due to project deployment.